# Rails select tag with required true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

I have the following select tag

```
<%= f.select :id, User.find(:all, :conditions => ["manager = ?", false]).collect {|u| [u.username, u.id]}, {:required => true}, {:class => "multiselect", :multiple => true} %>
```

I try to add `:required => true` to it, the view renders but `:required => true` doesn't work!.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a bit late, but for anyone looking, checking at the [reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select), should go explicitly as the hash, so ruby interpreter doesn't get confused:

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

For this special case:

```
<%= f.select :id,
             User.find(:all, :conditions => ["manager = ?", false]).collect {|u| [u.username, u.id]},
             {:prompt => 'Select something'},
             {:required => true, :class => "multiselect", :multiple => true} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :id, User.find(:all, :conditions => ["manager = ?", false]).collect {|u| [u.username, u.id]}, {:multiple => true}, :class => "multiselect", :required => true %>
```

Comment: lol, did you try moving multiple outside the hash? that should make the trick.

Comment: which version of rails are you using? the conditions hash is old rails 2 syntax

Comment: I use Rails 4, what I can use other than conditions?